# jshint: use node options, but disallow console statements?

Tags: node.js, jshint

I'm using jshint and I'd like to use the `node` option, but I'd also like to disallow console statements.

Is this possible? I've been reading the [jshint options documentation](http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/) without luck.

Things I've tried that have failed:

```
"node": true,
"globals": { 
  "console": false
}
```

Also:

```
"node": true,
"devel": false
```

I guess I could set `"node": false` and then explicitly add everything to `globals`, but that seems ugly.

Comment: Seems that jshint allows `console` when you `"node": true`, and then you cant disallow it anyway :(

Answer (score 9):

First of all the syntax:

```
"globals": {
    "console": false
}
```

Is to *allow* console as a read only variable, so not what you want.

What does appear to work is the following setting:

```
"predef": ["-console"]
```

I couldn't find this directly documented, but the docs (http://jshint.com/docs/) mention the `predef` jshintrc option, and later talk about inline global blacklists (e.g. `/* global -BLACKLIST */`) and tests show that combining the two does work.